# Concerning PTHREAD_MUTEX_ROBUST

Tags: pthreads, posix, ipc, mutex, language-lawyer

According to the official [doc](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutexattr_getrobust.html) (emphasis mine):

> PTHREAD_MUTEX_ROBUST
>   If the process containing the owning thread of
>   a robust mutex terminates while holding the mutex lock, the next
>   thread that acquires the mutex ***shall*** be notified about the termination
>   by the return value [EOWNERDEAD] from the locking function. If the
>   owning thread of a robust mutex terminates while holding the mutex
>   lock, the next thread that acquires the mutex ***may*** be notified about
>   the termination by the return value [EOWNERDEAD]...

The doc seems to be differentiating specifically the cases for out-of-process and in-process thread termination and have chosen the wording ***shall*** and ***may*** carefully. Does this imply that the robustness is mandatory in the out-of-process case, but is optional in the in-process case (which may result in a deadlock)?